# drag and drop an item in an svg image with curved shape

Tags: svg, drag-and-drop

I have an SVG image of three circles and making Venn-diagram with cross sections.
And I want to drop some objects in each section and find out each object is in which section.

My SVG image is created by seven layers, I want to know in which layer my object is dropped.

Comment: Please edit your question and provide what have you tried so far..

Comment: There's possibly a couple of ways, but people need a bit more info. Can you at least provide the SVG for the diagram on a jsfiddle, ideally with a bit of dragging going on. It may well also depend on the objects being dragged, so include those as well.